# Jmeter clear cookies after SOME iteration

Tags: cookies, jmeter

In jmeter cookie manager you can just clear cookies in each iteration or not.

**Question**
But what I need is that Jmeter should clear cookies after some iteration. Eg. 2 or 3

**Why?**
I need this beceause I dont want to overload the server with new cookie data each time. I will send 30 k request but I need  just 15 k new session.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using some scripting, i.e:

1. Add Beanshell PreProcessor as a child of the very first HTTP Request sampler
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   if (vars.getIteration() == 2) {
       sampler.getCookieManager().clear();
   }
   ```

   Where:

   - `vars` - an instance of [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html), provides access to all JMeter Variables, including current iteration number
   - `sampler` - an entity representing the parent Sampler for the Beanshell PreProcessor, in case of HTTP Request samplers - [HTTPSamplerProxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerProxy.html)

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) article to get started with scripting in JMeter tests.